# Android: real-time friend list update

Tags: android, multithreading, time, refresh

I just made an app where a friend list is being updated in real time depending on if you get blocked or deleted by one of your friends, so I refresh the list on the screen. However, I was wondering what would be appropriate as the time interval for updates using threads? right now I am using 1 second but I think it's a bit exaggerated.

Answer (score 0):

I would have it as user defined. If you set a default time that is unchangeable, some users may think it is running the thread too often. They may also think your app is causing bad battery life. Just have a few options like Twitter or Facebook. Something like 1,5,10,30,60,180,etc.